# Using a javascript variable inside the <p> element

Tags: javascript, html

I created an id for the variable I wanted to use but can't find how to insert it in the p element. When I try this I get "Uncaught type error: cannot set property of 'innerHTML' of null(...).

```
var str = array.toString();
       document.getElementById('variable').innerHTML = str;
<p> Start of sentence  <id = "variable" />,  end of sentence</p>
```

answer to this question is to use span tag.

Answer (score 3):

If the code is exactly as in your snippet, then it's not working for 2 reasons;

1. You're trying to `getElementById` before the DOM contains the element with id 'variable' - to solve that run the script on page load or at least after the element is declared.
2. I've never seen anyone do

   ```
    <id="variable"/>
   ```

and try to reference it, I would do

```
    <span id="variable"></span>
```

and reference that with `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML syntax is wrong.

Instead of

```
<p> Start of sentence  <id = "variable" />,  end of sentence</p>
```

You should have:

```
<p id="variable"> Start of sentence  ,  end of sentence</p>
```

Id is an **attribute**, not a tag. Therefore, it must be nested within a tag, in this case the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Sorry we only briefly went over html but i'm trying to get the variable inside the middle of my sentence without creating a new paragraph.

Comment: You can't do this with plain HTML/Javascript, you need some kind of templating framework (by this I mean your id syntax). I've never seen this kind of syntax before. What templating library are you using?